# IntentService can't be invoked from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentservice

I need to update my app's contnent everyday and I use AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and IntentService for it.

I create AlarmManager object and setRepeating in the class that extends from Application class:

```
 private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmReceiver.ACTION_ALARM);
          AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                     1234567, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
          System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pIntent);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

My BroadcastReceiver get's message successfully :

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    public static String ACTION_ALARM = "com.alarammanager.alaram";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        downloader.setAction(Constants.UPDATE_SERVICE);
        context.startService(downloader);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But I also need to start IntentService from the BroadcastReceiver, but it don't started from onReceiver's method of BroadcastReceiver. My service:

```
<service android:name="com.services.UpdateService" 
        android:enabled="true">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.service.UpdateService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And class for it.

```
public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

        public UpdateService() {
            super("UpdateService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("UpdateService", "About to execute MyTask");
            //  new MyTask().execute();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "updateService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Sometimes overriding onStartCommand will not call onHandleIntent
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.i("asdasd", "here..!");
            return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        }
    }
```

My question is why does it(IntentService) can't be invoked from BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: remove onStartCommand method..

Comment: tried withot it and got the same reult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service
>   by calling startService(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied
>   and a unique integer token representing the start request. Do not call
>   this method directly.

If you do call then this is the preferred way:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```